# Time Overlay on WebCam Stream

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I want to encode or add timestamp on the image. as this is part of a web application, running on the remote device. What is the best way to approach this? How can I add time.time() on to the image itself using cv2.

If any other suggestions, please feel free to suggest

```
class CameraDevice():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.time = time() #timestamp
        self.cap.set(3, 640)
        self.cap.set(4, 480)

def rotate(self, frame):
    if flip:
        (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
        center = (w/2, h/2)
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 180, 1.0)
        frame = cv2.warpAffine(frame, M, (w, h))
    return frame

async def get_latest_frame(self):
    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return self.rotate(frame)

async def get_jpeg_frame(self):
    encode_param = (int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90)
    frame = await self.get_latest_frame()
    frame, encimg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
    return encimg.tostring()
```

Comment: You can use [`cv2.putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin)) to draw text information

Answer (score -1):

You can use PIL to add a date on each frame.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

...
pil_frame = Image.fromarray(img)
drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_frame)
black = (3, 8, 12)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 40)
drawing.text(pos, text, fill=black, font=font)
...
```

Check this link : http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/10/17/how-to-watermark-your-photos-with-python/

Comment: I was looking more into the adding timeoverlay to video onto cv2 contructor. this is a completly diffrent path. thanks though